# Register a SpringBootApplication itself as an ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, events, actionlistener

Is it possible that the main class of a SpringBoot application which is annotated with @SpringBootApplication registers itself as a listener for context events?

I tried it on the one hand by letting the main class implement ApplicationListener and on the other hand by annotating a method as an EventListener

```
@EventListener
private void lockFields(final List<String> customfieldNames) {
    System.out.println("Ruuuuunnnnnn....");
}
```

but whenever I start my application the event is not caught (or not fired at all?).

How can I achieve this?

What I intend to do is to change some values in a database before the actual application starts...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by implementing ApplicationListener interface

```
implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>
```

and implementing

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
```